# Как сделать фронтенд (интерфейс программы) на C++, а бекенд (логика программы) на Python?

Tags: python, c++

Хочу написать программку с интерфейсом. Изначально хотел писать на чистом питоне без модулей. Узнал, что на чистом не возможно, только на С. Выбрал С++. Теперь стоит вопрос: как можно объединить код из с++ и питона?

Comment: Хотите писать на _чистом_ питоне, и поэтому пытаетесь прикрутить к питону модуль на _другом языке_? Уверены, что склепать интерфейс программы на C++ будет проще?

Comment: @wololo, читайте внимательней. Написано хотеЛ. Узнало то, что никак и теперь хочу связать с плюсы и питон

Comment: Так а чего бы не связать питон с питоновскими модулями для интерфейса? Или там таких модулей нет?

Comment: Модули то есть, но мне интересно попробовать не с помощью модулей питон, а как-то по-другому.

Comment: О, мсье знает толк в извращениях :). Не знаю в чем ваши проблемы, но например и для фронта и для логики можно использовать один язык. У фреймфорка Qt есть реализация на с++ и на  питон (PyQt, PySide)

Comment: Да, знаю о qt на python, но мне скучно и делать нечего. :)

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно написать API для взаимодействия программ.

Допустим есть апи на c++, которая возвращает какой-то формат данных и на Python вы сможете  его принимать, обрабатывать и т.д

Comment: а как написать апи?

Comment: по сути вы пересказали мой вопрос другими словами

Comment: [Как нарисовать сову...](https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/2016/11/12/11/og_og_147897761127285925.jpg)

Comment: @Dariuz любым способом. Можете возвращать данные в JSON, можете придумать свой формат и парсер под него, можете возвращать коды... Главное, чтобы модули понимали друг друга. Это не простая задача, но она легко гуглится. Поищите